# Superset: how does filter_immune_slice_fields work?

Tags: filter, dashboard, apache-superset

I'd like to apply a filter in a dashboard with 5 different charts only to two of these.

I've found "filter_immune_slice_fields" but O can't understand how it works. So, can anyone help me an intuitive example?

In https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html I don't understand what the numbers mean in this sentence: "slices 324, 65 and 92" and where I can find the name of the filter.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working, then we can help you with that.

Comment: Hi @DanielWalker thank you to your reply. I have an attempt: a dashboard with 5 different charts only to two of these. i've tried to modify the JSON Metadata 
"{"filter_immune_slices": [], "timed_refresh_immune_slices": [], "filter_immune_slice_fields": {"180": ["annorif"]}" but that is not working. I think to mistake what to write in filter_immune_slice_fields. This is my question: what number i have to write? is it related to my chart? if yes, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers to add in the `"filter_immune_slices": []` are the `chartId`'s of each slice you want to exclude from the dashboard level filtering. The `chartId` of any slide can be found in the "Edit Dashboard" form, inside Position JSON filed, where for each Slice there is a meta JSON object like that:

```
"meta":{"chartId":29,"height":49,"sliceName":"Top Chart","width":6}
```

In this sample 29 is the number to use.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `"filter_immune_slices"` I had to include slice_id to the `"excluded"` field also in each filter's scope property:

[image]